# Retrofit enqueue doesn't work but execute work

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit

I'm using **com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0**

```
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);


    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:9000")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();

    final UserService service = retrofit.create(UserService.class);

    Call<User> userCall = service.createUser(user)
```

Here is the problem: when I run the `execute` it make REST API request but when I use `enqueue` it does nothing (no exception, no log)

```
  userCall.execute(); //this work

  //this does not work
  userCall.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
          // no response 
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
          //nothing here
      }
  });
```

Comment: But can you see in logs, that the request has been made?

Comment: no, there is no log when I run it. but when I ran execute it shows the log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well,

The issue was because I was using an emulator and try to call the localhost however, it turn out if you want call the localhost you have to use this ip `10.0.2.2`

The `execute` works because I was running as unit test but when it runs `enqueue` I think it need to run on android platform.

refer to this
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#networkaddresses

[How to get the Android Emulator's IP address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720346/how-to-get-the-android-emulators-ip-address)

Comment: In case you want to run your web-services on a localhost .You can always define  ip to redirec via modifying  host file of emulator.That is well to go option without any hassles.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this full Answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42835973/1597844)

Here is the shortest code snippest.

```
    private void emailLoginRequest() {
    LoginService loginService = ApiFactory.createService(LoginService.class);
    Call<JsonObject> call = loginService.login(edtEmail.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString(),mDeviceType,mDeviceToken);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
            hideProgressDialog();
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                LOGD(TAG, "onResponse 0: " + response.body().toString());
                LoginResponse loginResponse = new Gson().fromJson(response.body().toString(), LoginResponse.class);

                System.out.println("+++ get message >> " + loginResponse.getMessage());
                int status = loginResponse.getStatus();

            }else {
                LOGD(TAG, "response fail 0: " + response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
            hideProgressDialog();
            LOGD(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put your code as this:

```
 userCall.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "in response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "in response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
});
```

Now based on method call you will get toast if its in response toast will be "In response" don't forget write youractivity name before this  like :  MainActivity.this

Comment: well both methods do not get called

Answer (score 0):

[see this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests)

retrofit can be called by 2 methods separately one is synchronous and another way is asynchronous.

enqueue is an asynchronous way where it does not wait for a response and proceed. here you need to handle Call separately to load UI later.

Execute is asynchronously call rest api and wait until get response and process it.

choice wisely