# Is there a way to know what is volley going to parse?

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley

I use this code to make requests to a server, it usually works fine but sometimes it throws some errors since its under development, however if it throws an error volley tries to parse it into a JsonObject and will inevitably fail.

```
final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, baseUrl, postparams, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.w("Response", response.toString());
                        callBackActivity.JsonCallback(response, "grupos");
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        callBackActivity.ErrorCallback(error, "grupos");

                    }
                });
```

So is there any way to know whats the raw response of the server before parsing it into a JsonObject?

Comment: You can switch to Retrofit and use `HttpLoggingInterceptor` [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835315/httplogginginterceptor-for-http-request-response-logging) that will Log every request and response, their times and headers. Or if Volley uses `OkHttp` too (IDK), no need to switch anything, just add the thing to the `OkHttp`.

Comment: Will check it out, thanks for the advice.

Comment: what http response are you sending back to android client upon error? volley's error listener should be called upon any kind of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `JSONObjecRequest` try `StringRequest` which will give the response in string. Log this response and look what is causing the error, then you can revert it back to JSONObjectRequest

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.v(response)
        try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);       
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("exception is " + e.toString());
            }        }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //error log
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative but im currently looking for an option that can work for both scenarios, an error and a succesful connection.

Comment: You can use for successful case as well...you can convert the response to `JSONObject` and use the JSONObject....I do the same in my projects

Comment: Ah, so the stringrequest accepts both jsons and plaintext and if inside the response i try to convert it and it fails then i can check what was the response, right?

Comment: Thats right...i have updated the answer for you to refer

Comment: Yeah that should work out just fine, thanks for your input!